# Are there any molecules with delta bonds in their ground states?

Tags: bond, orbitals

When looking at excited states of molecules, $\delta$ bonds are relatively common, but I've never come across a molecule with a $\delta$ bond in its ground state.

Are there molecules with $\delta$ bonds in their ground states?

What about even higher angular momentum states ($\phi$ and $\gamma$ bonds)?

Comment: Re: phi/gamma bonds, [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextuple_bond) `There is strong evidence to believe that no two elements in the periodic table can form a bond with greater order than 6` and links to http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/anie.200603600/abstract. Guess it's relevant here. It may not make phi/gamma bonds _impossible_, but probably makes them  rarer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Chromium(II) acetate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium%28II%29_acetate) has a Cr-Cr quadruple bond - and hence a $\delta$ bond - in its ground state. This sort of "paddlewheel" configuration, with four carboxylic acids coordinating a pair of metal ions, is reasonably common (see also copper(II) acetate, for instance), although the extent to which the metals can be considered covalently bonded varies.

Comment: The copper analog is another example

Answer (score 7):

Metal-metal quadruple bonds have seemingly been reported for several cases, quite often by F. A. Cotton. A short search revealed a more recent report on a species with a Cr-Cr quintuple bond: [Synthesis of a Stable Compound with Fivefold Bonding Between Two Chromium(I) Centers](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/310/5749/844).

Admittedly, I didn't bother to read the full article, it's just not the kind of chemistry I'm interested in. However, YMMV and you might find it helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I am a bit late to the party, but I just found this question. When I did research on the φ bond for [What would follow in the series sigma, pi and delta bonds?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/27532/4945) I came across some predictions about possible φ bond in the ground state.

According to Gagliardi and Roos, there should be a φ bond in the ground state of the $\ce{U2}$ molecule. That being said, it is probably incredibly tough to synthesise this molecule.

Metal-metal multiple bonds have become fairly common as [my earlier answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/31782/4945) demonstrates.
It should be clarified  that a quadruple bond does not necessarily mean that a δ bond is involved. Often enough the combination of the d<sub>z²</sub> metal orbitals lead to the formation of a second σ bond first.
It should further be explained, that a δ bond can be present, but the overall bond order could be lower than four.

[Laura Gagliardi, Björn O. Roos, *Nature*, **2005**, *433*, 848-851.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature03249) Available free at [Archive ouverte UNIGE](http://archive-ouverte.unige.ch/unige:3652).

Comment: I figure you could make $\ce{U2}$ molecules by heating the metal enough so that becomes gaseous. Either find a chamber that resists temperatures of around $\mathrm{4000\ K}$ to get a decently high vapour pressure, or more likely, do some kind of ablation (plasma, laser, etc) on solid uranium, though there would probably be contamination with larger metallic clusters.