# What kind of bonds can form between benzene and transition metals in π-complexes?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, orbitals, organometallic-compounds, symmetry

I'm trying to draw the six π-orbitals (3 bonding, which are filled, and 3 anti-bonding) of a benzene ring when it complexes with metal d-orbitals and which metal orbitals have the correct symmetry ($\sigma$, π, $\delta$) to overlap with each of them. I know that metal orbitals will only form a bonding interaction with ligand orbitals if they have matching symmetry but I am not sure which ones will interact.

I think a π bond is formed between $e_{1g}$ of benzene and $d_{xy}$ and $d_{yz}$. Also a $\sigma$ bond is formed between $a_{2u}$ of the benzene and $d_{z^2}$ and $a_{2u}$. No δ bond is formed.

Answer (score 4):

In theory benzene and a transition metal could form σ, π, δ, [and even φ](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/27532/4945) bonds as the symmetry allows this.

Here are the orbitals of benzene, calculated at the PBE0/def2-TZVPP level of theory in the *D*<sub>6h</sub>  point group with Gamess.

[image: pi orbitals of benzene, total density]

The (valence) orbitals of chromium on the same level of theory in the same point group are as follows:

[image: valence orbitals of chromium]

The linear combination of these orbitals would yield orbitals that have the above mentioned bond symmetries. We will ignore for now that they will most likely not occupied in a complex like [bis(benzene)chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bis(benzene)chromium).

- benzene a<sub>2u</sub> + Cr s → σ
- benzene a<sub>2u</sub> + Cr d<sub>z²</sub> → σ
- benzene e<sub>1g</sub> + Cr d<sub>xz</sub> → π
- benzene e<sub>1g</sub> + Cr d<sub>yz</sub> → π
- benzene e<sub>2u</sub> + Cr d<sub>xy</sub> → δ
- benzene e<sub>2u</sub> + Cr d<sub>x²-y²</sub> → δ

If we look at f-orbitals (that is of course not very feasible for chromium), we could construct another bond type:

- benzene a<sub>1g</sub> + Cr f<sub>x(x2−3y2)</sub> → φ

The necessary orbital looks like this:

[image: f-type orbital of chromium]

Of course which of these bonds will form or not depends on the metal in question, the occupation of the orbitals and more. After all, there are also p orbitals which can overlap to form σ and π bonds.

---

*Colour code:* Occupied orbitals are shown in blue and orange, while virtual orbitals are shown in yellow and red. Phases have been assigned randomly. The total density of the molecule uses a violet contour.