# Why is maximum number of covalent bonds 3?

Tags: bond, orbitals, molecules, valence-bond-theory

In my textbook it is mentioned that maximum 3 covalent bonds can be formed within 2 atoms, which makes sense as 1 p orbital from each can be used for sigma bond and the remaining 2 can form pi bonds. But d subshell contains 5 d-orbitals, so why is it not possible to form 5 bonds?

I tried searching for it but couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: W2 and Mo2 form sextuple (6) bonds.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextuple_bond

Comment: But anything more than 3 is rare.

Comment: Perhaps more importantly, anything more than 3 is _impossible_ for carbon.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/594/bonding-in-diatomic-c2-a-carbon-carbon-quadruple-bond https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27532/what-would-follow-in-the-series-sigma-pi-and-delta-bonds

Comment: Unfortunately this question hinges on the definition of bond. And the whole concept of a bond is still very much debated and not clear at all. There's no point in going down this rabbit hole before some decent understanding of quantum mechanics. The carbon dimer is actually a nice point in case for this ongoing debate; I think we have a question for that.