What is the bonding of p block elements in gas phase?
What is the molecular structure of the vapours of the solid p block elements like silicon, carbon, lead. I would like to focus the question to the main structure that exists in vapours but if any theoretical or experimental dimers can be formed, please feel free to mention.

This question is similar to: Which elements can be diatomic?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I understand the concerns about this question. I am not particularly focusing on diatomic nature but just generally the nature of solids as gases. I am also looking at the bonds formed between if there are any diatomic molecules

OK, that's different now, but seems too broad there's for ex. more specific https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/594/bonding-in-diatomic-c2-a-carbon-carbon-quadruple-bond
